# Build intelligent path between source and target in d3.js

Tags: javascript, angular, d3.js

I am trying to create points between source to target. Somehow, I am able to create points but they are not good enough. At some point, the path overlap over other shapes.

Just an example, path is overlapping the other shapes. In this case, from source to target, I am breaking path in half. So, it works if path is connecting to next shape but doesn't work, if next shape is far like in below case.

There can be many source shapes may be 3,4 or 10 and there can be multiple targets as well. I can not clearly defined some fixed path.

Comment: Can you post your data model?

Comment: @MichaelRovinsky I have added data model in question

Comment: @MichaelRovinsky below code works fine if we have 3 shapes and one target. but it doesn't create correct path if we have more source and target shapes. please check my updated question. Somehow, I need to find proper path for target, because I am placing 5 shapes in single row, next shape will come in the next row. So, it may happen that target may come in next row.

Comment: I don't think there is a possibility to create a simple yet universal path builder for any type of layout. Especially, when you have not only to draw a path between two nodes but also take into consideration other nodes, and you don't know how many nodes you have at all. Just try to draw every possible case on a paper and you'll get into an endless process... Anyway, If you have a very limited number of scenarios, please draw them at once, and post in a new question. I will try to answer

Comment: @MichaelRovinsky thanks for your help and providing me some understanding around it. I think are no so many scenarios, I have mentioned some scenarios which will be covered here in this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67668788/building-path-between-nodes-with-possible-scenarios

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `getPath` function to calculate a link path:

```
const getPath = link => `M ${link.fromX},${link.fromY} H ${link.fromX + 50} V ${link.toY} H ${link.toX}`;
```

See how it works in the snippet:

```js
const data = [
    {
        "shapeName": "rect1",
        "shapeId": "1.1",
        "coordinateData": {
            "height": 125,
            "width": 100,
            "xCoordinate": 300,
            "yCoordinate": 100
        },
        "ticks": [
            {
                "tickId": "1.1.1",
                "sourceTarget": [
                    {
                        "sourceTick": "1.1.1",
                        "targetTick": "1.4.11"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    
    },
    {
        "shapeName": "rect2",
        "shapeId": "1.2",
        "coordinateData": {
            "height": 125,
            "width": 100,
            "xCoordinate": 850,
            "yCoordinate": 100
        },
        "ticks": [
            {
                "tickId": "1.2.1",
                "sourceTarget": [
                    {
                        "sourceTick": "1.2.1",
                        "targetTick": "1.4.12"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    
    },
    {
        "shapeName": "rect3",
        "shapeId": "1.3",
        "coordinateData": {
            "height": 125,
            "width": 100,
            "xCoordinate": 1400,
            "yCoordinate": 100
        },
        "ticks": [
            {
                "tickId": "1.3.1",
                "sourceTarget": [
                    {
                        "sourceTick": "1.3.1",
                        "targetTick": "1.4.13"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    
    },
    {
        "shapeName": "rect4",
        "shapeId": "1.4",
        "coordinateData": {
            "height": 375,
            "width": 100,
            "xCoordinate": 1750,
            "yCoordinate": 100
        },
        "ticks": [
            {
                "tickId": "1.4.11",
                "sourceTarget": null
            },
            {
                "tickId": "1.4.12",
                "sourceTarget": null
            },
            {
                "tickId": "1.4.13",
                "sourceTarget": null
            }
        ]
    
    }
];


const svg = d3.select('svg');

svg.selectAll('rect.shape')
  .data(data, d => d.shapeId)
  .enter()
  .append('rect')
  .classed('shape', true)
  .attr('width', d => d.coordinateData.width)
  .attr('height', d => d.coordinateData.height)
  .attr('x', d => d.coordinateData.xCoordinate)
  .attr('y', d => d.coordinateData.yCoordinate);
   
    
const ticks = data.reduce((all, item) => {
 item.ticks.forEach((tick, index) => {
  const x = item.coordinateData.xCoordinate + (tick.sourceTarget ? item.coordinateData.width : 0);
  const y = item.coordinateData.yCoordinate + item.coordinateData.height / 2 + (index - (item.ticks.length - 1) / 2) * 30; 
  all.push({id: tick.tickId, target: tick.sourceTarget ? tick.sourceTarget[0].targetTick : null, x, y});
  });
  return all;
}, []);    

svg.selectAll('circle.tick')
  .data(ticks, d => d.id)
  .enter()
  .append('circle')
  .classed('tick', true)
  .attr('cx', d => d.x)
  .attr('cy', d => d.y)
  .attr('r', 10)

const links = ticks.filter(d => d.target).map((tick, index) => {
  const target = ticks.find(t => t.id === tick.target);
  return {id: index, fromX: tick.x, fromY: tick.y, toX: target.x, toY: target.y};
});

const getPath = link => `M ${link.fromX},${link.fromY} H ${link.fromX + 50} V ${link.toY} H ${link.toX}`;

svg.selectAll('path.link')
  .data(links, d => d.id)
  .enter()
  .append('path')
  .classed('link', true)
  .attr('d', getPath)
```

```css
svg {
  border: 1px solid gray;
}
path, .shape {
  stroke-width: 1;
  stroke: black;
  fill: none;
}

.tick {
  fill: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg width="600" height="150" viewBox="0 0 2000 500"/>
```