# Building path between nodes with possible scenarios

Tags: javascript, angular, d3.js

I am trying to create link between two nodes with some possible scenarios as you can see in below image. The target will always be on right side in a row and target can be in the same row, next row or next to next row depend on number of shapes.

Single row contains 5 shapes including target shape. if we have 20 shapes and 1 target shape then there will be 5 rows, last will be target shape.

[image: Possible path for target]

Below is the data model for the source and target which will be used to create nodes and paths between.

```json
[
    {
        "shapeName": "rect1",
        "shapeId": "1.1",
        "coordinateData": {
            "height": 125,
            "width": 100,
            "xCoordinate": 300,
            "yCoordinate": 100
        },
        "ticks": [
            {
                "tickId": "1.1.1",
                "sourceTarget": [
                    {
                        "sourceTick": "1.1.1",
                        "targetTick": "1.4.11"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    
    },
    {
        "shapeName": "rect2",
        "shapeId": "1.2",
        "coordinateData": {
            "height": 125,
            "width": 100,
            "xCoordinate": 850,
            "yCoordinate": 100
        },
        "ticks": [
            {
                "tickId": "1.2.1",
                "sourceTarget": [
                    {
                        "sourceTick": "1.2.1",
                        "targetTick": "1.4.12"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    
    },
    {
        "shapeName": "rect3",
        "shapeId": "1.3",
        "coordinateData": {
            "height": 125,
            "width": 100,
            "xCoordinate": 1400,
            "yCoordinate": 100
        },
        "ticks": [
            {
                "tickId": "1.3.1",
                "sourceTarget": [
                    {
                        "sourceTick": "1.3.1",
                        "targetTick": "1.4.13"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    
    },
    {
        "shapeName": "rect4",
        "shapeId": "1.4",
        "coordinateData": {
            "height": 375,
            "width": 100,
            "xCoordinate": 1750,
            "yCoordinate": 100
        },
        "ticks": [
            {
                "tickId": "1.4.11",
                "sourceTarget": null
            },
            {
                "tickId": "1.4.12",
                "sourceTarget": null
            },
            {
                "tickId": "1.4.13",
                "sourceTarget": null
            }
        ]
    
    }
]
```

Thanks

Comment: Here is a problem with the bottom-right layout: How do we know to draw paths between the second and the third column? It might look obvious visually, but let's try to formalize it. Do you define rows and columns in your layout? Or should we first go over every node and classify its row and column?

Comment: @MichaelRovinsky No I am not defining row and column. I am just updating y index of shape after 5th shape while creating x and y index so that it will be place on next row. May be we will have to classify row and column.